# Implementing pushd in python

Tags: python, operating-system, yield, chdir, pushd

I am trying to understand how the following is an implementation of the Unix command pushd. Specifically what is the purpose of the yield command given that it yields nothing.

```
@contextmanager
def pushd(path):
    prev = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(prev)
```

According to wikipedia, 'pushd command saves the current working directory in memory so it can be returned to at any time, optionally changing to a new directory'. What part of this code block performs which functions in this definition?

Answer (score 3):

To understand this code you have to understand why @contextmanager decorator is used. It allows you to use some function in `with` statement, which will handle a *context* for you. So you want to do something in some directory and then jump back - your actions will make sense in a *context* of directory you jumped in. So the use case for this function looks like this:

```
In [4]: os.chdir('/var')                                                                                                                                                                     

In [5]: os.getcwd()                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: '/var'

In [6]: with pushd('/etc'): 
   ...:     print(os.getcwd()) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                      
/etc

In [7]: os.getcwd()                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[7]: '/var'
```

As you can see - a directory has changed to /etc inside `with` block, but after that it has returned to back to /var, resembling popd behavior.

yield in this case is a part of context manager decorator API and it doesn't need to return anything in this case. It is used constructions like

```
with open('my_file.txt') as file:
   do_something_with_file(file)
```

where you actually need some resource to work on inside context.

Refer to [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) documentation to read more about the goals of the module.